# No response for API call using $resource in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find my way around angularjs by following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_13) tutorial from the official site and changing it slightly to call a simple web API.
The Angularjs version is 1.6.4. The issue I am having is that I cannot see any data on the webpage. *I just get "[]" instead of data on the web page.*

I have been through the first few results of [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=angularjs+%24resource+not+fetching+data&oq=angularjs+%24resource+not+fetching+data&aqs=chrome..69i57.9881j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=angularjs+resource+getting+empty+array&start=0) google search and some others but the issue persists.

**The web API:**

This returns data in the format below (JSON) and I have confirmed this using postman and the browser.

```
[{"name":"gold","snippet":"bob is the name!"},{"name":"silver"},{"name":"bronze"}]
```

**The service to get the data**

```
angular.
  module('core.phone').
  factory('Phone', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:xxxxx/api/test', {}, {
        query: {
                    method: 'GET',
//                  transformResponse: function (data) {return angular.fromJson(data)},
          isArray: true
        }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

**The controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['Phone',
      function PhoneListController(Phone) {
        this.phones = Phone.query() ;
/*
                Phone.query().$promise.then(function (res) {
                this.phones = res ;
                } ) ;
*/
        this.orderProp = 'age' ;
      }
    ]
  });
```

**The template (The part where I hope to see some output)**

```
<ul class="phones">
    <p>{{$ctrl.phones}}</p>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones">
                <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
    </li>
    .......
```

Most of the search results seem to indicate that its the asynchronous nature of angularjs calls which is causing it. Some suggested using transformResponse to fix it. None have worked so far.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Use the `.catch` method of the `$promise` to see the error. A status of -1 usually indicates a CORS problem.

Comment: You have some redundancy in your resource definition. You can simply use `return $resource('http://localhost:58082/api/test');`. The *query* action is already set to use GET and `isArray: true`

Comment: Are there any errors in your JS / *Networking*  console(s)?

Comment: Thanks George! CORS was the culprit so it was actually a server side issue (nodejs). Not an angularjs issue at all. Followed [these](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) instructions and make changes to the server side (serving the web API requests) and all is well again.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Your comment about the cosoles got me to dig up the mozilla browser console (which I did not even know existed!) which in turn helped to confirm the CORS issue. Also, I agree that the code seems redundant but the intention is to add more stuff to the call, so I left it dangling there.